# VLookup in UDF in Sub vs Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, vlookup

I have simple UDF supposed to change the value of a VLookUp Function in case no value is found.

```
Function get_value(what,where) 'what ->  e.g. 01/31/2020,02/28/2020
                               'where -> Sheet2!A:B
jump:
If IsError(Application.VLookup(what,where,2,False)) Then
  what = what - 1
  GoTo jump
   
  Else
  get_value = Application.VLookup(what,where,2,False)

  EndIf

End Function
```

When calling the function in a sub everything works as intended!

However, calling the function in a Worksheet (i.e `=get_value(A2,Sheet2!A;B)`, whenever there is no value for the date of A2 and the `what` is supposed to be changed in the loop (to look up the value of the new date i.e. `02/28/2020`  to `02/27/2020`)
the function returns `#VALUE!` instead of the actual value for `02/27/2020`

I have tried using  a `Do While`Loop instead of `GoTo` but this does not solve it.

I come from Python and this circuity in VBA leaves me baffled...

Comment: can't you just sort the 'where' range on the date and use a _range_ VLOOKUP ? Combined with IFERROR to get you covered ?  Simpler and faster !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `Do` loop (and specifying a maximum number of iterations in case `what` is never found):

```
Function get_value( _
    ByVal what As Date, _
    ByVal where As Range _
) As Variant
                  
    Const maxIterations As Long = 100 ' change as needed

    Do
        get_value = Application.VLookup(CLng(what), where, 2, False)
        what = what - 1
        
        Dim counter As Long
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop While IsError(get_value) And counter < maxIterations

End Function
```

Using `CLng` on `what` is what seems to be the trick here. In testing, your version was an infinite loop; `what` was never found. `VLookup` and dates can be finicky. However, `GoTo` is generally to be avoided, as it's a slippery slope towards spaghetti code.

Comment: that works! Can you give a reason why my approach does not work on a Worksheet?

Comment: I think the `CLng` actually is the trick. In testing, your code is an infinite loop. But `GoTo` is generally better avoided, so I've rewritten.